# Getting error when using ra-graphql-simple with react-admin

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, react-admin

My react-admin imp seems to be able to connect to a strapi api I've spun up and configured with the graphql plugin, but I get an error saying my client essentially doesn't know one of my strapi collections exists:

> Unknown resource 'products'. Make sure it has been declared on your server side schema. Known resources are

That's the full message that appears in a flash. No actual list of resources.

My App.js is the following:

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { dataProvider: null };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    buildGraphQLProvider({
      clientOptions: {
        uri: 'http://localhost:1337/graphql',
      },
    }).then(dataProvider => {
      this.setState({ dataProvider })
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { dataProvider } = this.state;
    if (!dataProvider) {
      return <div>Loading</div>;
    }
    return (
      <Admin
        authProvider={authProvider}
        dataProvider={dataProvider}
        i18nProvider={i18nProvider}
        title="GridPlus"
        locale="en"
        customRoutes={[
            <Route
                exact
                path="/custom"
                component={CustomRouteNoLayout}
                noLayout
            />,
            <Route exact path="/custom2" component={CustomRouteLayout} />,
        ]}>
        <Resource name="products" {...products} />
    </Admin>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Any ideas why admin-client isn't able to see my products collection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`ra-data-graphql-simple` send an introspection query to your graphql backend when it starts, gathering all possible resources matching the gql dialect it understands.

A dialect is a way to name the queries and mutations for each resource. For a resource to be detected, your schema must have the expected shape defined in the [documentation](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/packages/ra-data-graphql-simple#expected-graphql-schema).

Most of the time, you'll have to implement your own dialect using `ra-data-graphql`.

Comment: I'm not married to strapi. What's the simplest way for me to get a graphql api set up such that I can use it with react-admin? Would it be fairly easy for me to implement a dialect parser or should I just stand up a new api?

Comment: As an aside, here is the response to the introspection request react-admin is making: https://gist.github.com/mateodelnorte/c01af95accf027c6fd1ee55f255a0081

Comment: Writing a reusable dialect for strapi would probably be really appreciated by others ;) You could check how the `ra-data-graphql-simple` is implemented.

Comment: Reading a gql query result is hard... Do you have the schema generated by Strapi for your resource ?

Comment: Yup. Here you go. Thanks. https://gist.github.com/mateodelnorte/d886f574b8bf3234f3aae0eedab84e39

Comment: So that confirms it. You do need to write a strapi dialect specific graphql dataProvider. It's not trivial but you have a good starting point with the `ra-data-graphql-simple` package. I'm afraid there is no simple way yet as we don't have many graphql dialects implemented as data providers. We support our own simple dialect which has been developped for tests and graphcool. Someone is working on a Prisma provider though.

Comment: There's one more way to use react-admin on top of your strapi API but it would require to write all gql queries yourself. If you're interested, I'll write a blog post about it. Just ping me :)